# User was removed

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm okay with the losing of rep when users go away. I get that. My question is, can we get something more meaningful than "User was removed"? Specifically, I'd like to know which question it was that lost the rep.

Comment: [This has been asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140063/user-was-removed-need-to-show-which-answer-question-loses-its-reputation), and nothing happened with it

Comment: For the record, asking these questions on meta.scifi is usually pretty pointless. Site-wide changes like this would have to be raised on the [main meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 12):

Alas, no. One of the key policies on SE is that your [voting is private and confidential](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts). If you received a notification of which of your answers had been upvoted, shortly after a user had deleted themselves (or been deleted), that would obviously breach the policy.

The last time this was asked on the main meta site, it was closed as [status-bydesign](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), e.g. *"the specified behavior is intentional and **not subject to change or correction.**"*

Comment: I'm not asking who it was, just the question that had the reputation change.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - You could use that info to work out who'd up/downvoted you.

Comment: Probably? I don't see it being something I could do without taking more effort than I'd like to expend, though.

Comment: @Richard I don't see how.  You'd be getting the same information as a regular up/downvote, which are anonymous for the same reason

Comment: If user X publicly quits and three minutes later you get a note that not only have you been docked 10 rep but it also says **on which questions** it would be easy to work out who/what/when you'd been upvoted.

Comment: @Richard A lot of users don't publicly quit, though, they just silently disappear. Even in the case where they do quit publicly so you know which of your posts they voted on, there's nothing you can do with that knowledge since they no longer have an account.